# What could be the max width of an HTML email blast?

Tags: html, email, width, blast

I made html email blasts that are supposed to be supported in almost every email (gmail, yahoo, aol, outlook, etc.). I always set the width to `650px` for the html email blast, but now I set it to `990px`. I need to know whether this will be a problem or it is fine to use for html emails.

"@sawa 12 hours of work then asking a question at 7am with no sleep grammar smartass"

Comment: The width on my phone is less than `990px`.

Answer (score 1):

990px is too wide for most clients, especially mobile.  Industry standard is still in the 550px to 650px range.

Comment: but wouldn't they still be able to view it on mobile by swiping left to right.. not in the sense of responsiveness but like you can still view it going left to right.

Comment: They would be able to but very few users would bother to.  Without knowing more about your use case, it seems like you are creating a poor user experience.